# Android - Populate Multiple ListViews Through A Single Class

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity, populate

I have multiple activities which all have a ListView powered menu that appears on the click of a button.

These menus on each activity contain the same information, so instead of having to populate them by copying and pasting large amounts of code into each activity, I would like to have one class that will get the data and populate it.

One or two lines of code in each activity is fine, but I really want to slim this down as much as possible.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks,
Ashley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyCustomActivity extends Activity
```

seems to be the best way ;-)

You can insclude all the common code there.

If this menu is exactly the same you will just have to say for each one of your activity:

```
ActivityA extends MyCustomActivity
ActivityB extends MyCustomActivity
ActivityC extends MyCustomActivity
```

Here is an example that I used, because all my activity had the same code: 
https://github.com/iRail/BeTrains-for-Android/blob/master/src/tof/cv/mpp/Activity/BeTrainsActivity.java